# CDI - Injecting a SessionBean into a ServletContextListener triggered service

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jboss7.x, cdi, servletcontextlistener

I have a `ServletContextListener` implementation which calls some bean. I'm trying to inject a session bean into that bean, but the injected session bean always comes as `null`.

Could it be that the `BeanManager` is not initiated yet during `ServletContextListener` execution? Is there a known limitation for CDI and listeners? Or am I missing something in my code?

Here is the definition for the SessionBean I'm trying to inject -

```
@Stateless
@Local(MetricStubSessionLocal.class)
@Remote(MetricStubSessionRemote.class)
public class MetricStubSessionBean implements MetricStubSessionLocal,
    MetricStubSessionRemote {
    ...
}
```

And here is the Bean I'm trying to inject into -

```
public class MetricStubGeneratorJob implements IdpTimer {

    @Inject
    private MetricStubSession metricStubSession;

    private TimerStatus status;

    public MetricStubGeneratorJob() {
        super();
    }

    public MetricStubGeneratorJob(TimerStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should inject the local interface in your bean: `@Inject private MatricStubSessionLocal metricStubSession;`

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that didn't work. Anyway, my local interface is extending `MatricStubSession`...

Comment: How is your project structured - do you use EAR Deployment with the Session bean in EJB JAR and ServletContextListener in the WAR? What do you see in JBoss server.log? How do you inject MetricStubGeneratorJob to your ServletContextListener?

Comment: Could it be that the BeanManager is not initiated yet during ServletContextListener execution - no, because CDI runs before the servlet context.

Comment: @chearius I was able to `@Inject` the bean into the `ServletContextListener` but when I try to use the `EntityManager` to access the DB I'm getting this error in the server.log:  org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped

Comment: That's because at that moment there is no RequestContext. You should use @ApplicationScoped for the bean you inject in the SevletContextListener.

Comment: @chearius I have used `@ApplicationScoped` for the bean that I'm injecting into the `SevletContextListener` but I am still getting the same error regarding RequestScoped... Where else could that scope be coming from?

Comment: I've seen this error when injecting an `@ApplicationScoped` bean from a provider that had a `ServletContext` injected via `@Context` into a `ServletContextListener`.